# Read line delimited by comma and tab

Tags: matlab, io, scanf, textscan

I would like to read files containing numbers in each line. Here is the example of the format-

```
0,0,0   1   0   0   0
0.02,0.1,0.98   8.77    0.985292    0.112348    0.112348
0.04,0.2,1.96   8.77    0.985292    0.112348    0.224696
```

As above shown, the first three numbers are separated by commas, after that all the rest numbers are separated by tab in the line. As a result, it is not possible to use dlmread or textscan. Is there any way to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: You can use fscanf as described in this [link](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html). In `fscanf` you can specify the format of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should add two parameters in your function:

`Delimiter %choose the delimiter`

and

`MultipleDelimsAsOne %Treat Repeated Delimiters as One`

**Option 1:**

Small "trick" you can select more than one delimiter if you give a structure as input: `{',',' '}`.

```
Result = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f','Delimiter',{',',' '},'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
```

**Option 2:** (that should work)

This time I don't use `MultipleDelimsAsOne` but I precise that the delimiter can be a comma or a tab (with \t).

```
Result = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f','Delimiter',{',','\t'});
```